# Alternative for using $find and jquery selector in order to get object in ASP.net application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, controls, radwindow, clientid

I would like to call a method of an element which can be returned from the ASP.net Sys.Application method "$find". In this case it is a telerik RadWindow control (ID="MyWindow") and I would like to call the .show() method.

The problem is to get the correct client id of the control **in a separate JS file**, since IDs gets modified in the ASP.net framework. For this I currently use

```
$find($("[ID$=MyWindow]")[0].id).show();
```

This works if there is only one element on the page which id ends with "MyWindow". Unfortunately the control sometimes adds some strange wrapper element to the page which id ends with "MyWindow", too.

So my question: Is there a better way to get the ASP.net element object **in a separate JS file** besides this ugly combination of $find and jquery selection?

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: @KarlAnderson ASP.NET 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a small JavaScript enclosure at the end of the page and add controls you wish to address in external files as needed.

```
<script>
var controls = new function () {
    return {
        radWinManagerMain: {
            ClientID: "<%= radWinManagerMain.ClientID %>"
        },
        radWinManagerSub: {
            ClientID: "<%= radWinManagerSub.ClientID %>"
        }
    };
}();
</script>
```

I was using two separate RadWindowManagers which I wanted to address in an external JS file. GetRadWindowManager() would have always returned the first RadWindowManager instance on the page. I therefore chose this approach.

When calling the function (which is implemented in external JS) I pass on a reference to controls which returns the IDs.

```
<telerik:NavigationNode NavigateUrl="javascript:showWindow(controls.radWinManagerMain,'winSettings');" value="settings" Text="Settings" SpriteCssClass="fa fa-cog" runat="server" />
```

In external JS file:

```
function showWindow(control, windowName) {
    $find(control.ClientID).open(null, windowName);
    some more code here...
}
```

I found the idea to this on: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/simplify-javascript-control-references-in-asp.net-webforms

Answer (score 2):

Only thing I can think of will be to use `ClientIDMode` to either `preditable` or `static`.

[Here is an example.](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/May/04/Whats-New-in-ASPNET-40-Part-Two-WebForms-and-Visual-Studio-Enhancements)

Even then you want to be careful about colliding IDs.

```
<telerik:RadWindowID="RadWindow1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ...>
</telerik:RadWindow>

// Separate JS File
function showForm(url) {
   var oWnd = $find("RadWindow1");
   oWnd.setUrl(url);
   oWnd.show();
}
```

### OR another apporach is to use RadWindowsManager

`RadWindowManager` lets you call `RadWindow` via ID from JavaScript.

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" ...>
   <Windows>
     <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server">
     </telerik:RadWindow>
   </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>

// Separate JS File
function showForm(url) {
   window.radopen(url, "RadWindow1");
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion solves the problem to get the correct object via `$find("MyWindow")`, but then I get exceptions inside the `Telerik.Web.UI` class. I guess this is because the Window contains some more telerik components which IDs gets messed up.
I also found the possibility to use a RadWindowManager, which I can use in this specific case. But what if it was another element which does not have a corresponding manager?

Comment: Telerik controls don't support `ClientIdMode="static"`. In fact they don't seem to support anything other than `ClientIdMode="AutoID"`, according to [Telerik's documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/troubleshooting/general-troubleshooting#setting-clientidmode-property-to-static-breaks-the-telerik-controls-functionality)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create an object with all the names of the controls in ASPX file and access it from your JS file.

ASPX file:

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" ...>
   <Windows>
     <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server">
     </telerik:RadWindow>
   </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>



<script type="text/javascript">
         var MyControls = {
                MyRadWindow: '<%= RadWindow1.ClientID %>'
         };
</script>
```

JS File:

```
$find(MyControls.MyRadWindow).show();
```